# Powershell Integration with ImageMagick / VIPS

Tags: powershell, vips

I am trying to iterate through a list of files on disk, run a command for each file using VIPS / ImageMagick, then output a file and move it to to a different directory. I can't seem to get the commands to work together.

Why are the variables $_Basefile not working in this command?

**Individual Commands for VIPS**

```
vips tiffsave input_file.tif output_file.tiff --args[...]
```

**PowerShell Commands**

```
ls | %{vips tiffsave $_BaseFile.tif $_BaseFile.tiff --compression jpeg --Q=90 --whateverelse }
```

**Update:** The answer marked correctly below worked. Thumbs up for the well explained reasons why it didn't work! The proper command is:

```
GCI -File -Filter "*.tif" | %{vips tiffsave "$($_.FullName)" "$($_.BaseName).tiff" --compression jpeg --Q=90}
```

Comment: LotPings got it. Updated the question above to show the answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To learn which methods/properties are exposed through the pipeline
  you should issue an `Get-ChildItem -File|Get-Member` or short `ls -File|gm`
- You'll see it's `$_.FullName` and `$_.BaseName` you need

So try:

```
GCI -File -Filter "*.tif" | %{vips tiffsave "$($_.FullName)" "$($_.BaseName).tiff" --compression jpeg --Q=90}
```

ls, dir, gci are all aliases of the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet